# How can I show the right side Gradle tab in Android Studio (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, sha1

I open my flutter project on android studio but the Gradle side tab on the right side is not appearing to me. I need it in order to get the SHA-1 code. What can I do to make it appear to me?

Answer (score 1):

Click
`Ctrl+Shift+A` (for Win/Linux)
or
`Cmd+Shift+A` (for Mac)
then type "`Gradle`"
And click on "`Gradle`" item in the list.

If In some cases the above doesn't work then,
click `Shift+Shift`
switch to "`Action`"
then type "`Gradle`"
and select "`Gradle`" item in the list.

Comment: I tried but, It does not appear to me.